# OData Exception Failed to execute OData Metadata request

Tags: s4sdk

I followed the instructions in this [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/02/05/deep-dive-8-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-leverage-principal-propagation-via-oauth-2-when-consuming-a-business-api-from-s4hana-cloud/) to configure Principal Propagation and OAuth2.  However, when I go to test my application, I receive the following error message (after being asked to sign into the SAP CP with my S/4HC user credentials via IdP).

```
Error: Failed to execute OData Metadata request.com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataException: Failed to execute OData Metadata request.
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:215)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.internalExecute(ODataQuery.java:167)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:105)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:150)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.execute(ODataQuery.java:136)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:197)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperRead.execute(FluentHelperRead.java:23)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperBasic.execute(FluentHelperBasic.java:85)
    at com.sap.s4hc.dbs.ManagePirServlet.doGet(ManagePirServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.sap.core.communication.server.CertValidatorFilter.doFilter(CertValidatorFilter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(RequestContextServletFilter.java:171)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextCallable.call(RequestContextCallable.java:95)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.servlet.RequestContextServletFilter.doFilter(RequestContextServletFilter.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpCachingHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpCachingHeaderFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.security.servlet.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.RestCsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(RestCsrfPreventionFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:621)
    at com.sap.cloud.runtime.impl.bridge.security.AbstractAuthenticator.invoke(AbstractAuthenticator.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invokeNextValve(TenantValidationValve.java:182)
    at com.sap.core.tenant.valve.TenantValidationValve.invoke(TenantValidationValve.java:97)
    at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.callNextValve(RequestTracingValve.java:101)
    at com.sap.js.statistics.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:57)
    at com.sap.core.js.monitoring.tomcat.valve.RequestTracingValve.invoke(RequestTracingValve.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:808)
Caused by: com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler$ErpODataException: 
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createException(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:105)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:86)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.createError(ODataVdmErrorResultHandler.java:31)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.internal.ODataConnectivityUtil.checkHttpStatus(ODataConnectivityUtil.java:185)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:131)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.cache.metadata.GuavaMetadataCache.getEdm(GuavaMetadataCache.java:110)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadMetadata(ODataQuery.java:250)
    at com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQuery.loadEntriesFromDestination(ODataQuery.java:213)
... 61 more
```

CODE

How can I troubleshoot this further?  I cant seem to find any more details in the logs.

My code:

```
final List<MaintainYearsPeriod> maintainYearsPeriod = new DefaultPlannedIndependentRequirementService().getAllMaintainYearsPeriod().top(50).execute();
writer.write(new Gson().toJson(maintainYearsPeriod)); 
response.setContentType(“application/json”);
```

Thanks,
Marty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem -- I think the issue was due to a missing scope on my destination setup in SAP Cloud Platform

Comment: Hello martym, thanks for sharing your answer. If your issue is resolved, please mark the answer as "accepted", so it is visible to other members of the community that this question is resolved. Thank you.